# How can I check the http response status code in a Spring Interceptor?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, http-status-codes, interceptor

It seems that the `HttpServletResponse` parameter passed to `HandlerInterceptor#postHandle` is write only: there is no `getStatus()` method there.

Any idea about how to find out which `HttpStatus` was set after the request?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this for unit testing? If so, just use MockHttpServletResponse, in which getStatus() is defined.

Comment: I want to keep a server-side history of all the GET performed, so that I can programmatically render the URL of a "Cancel" button. It can't be static because I can reach a particular page from many others.